# A temporary Popup appears in the Latest HTML Editor Extender control by AJAX

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax

I am having an issue using the HTML Editor Extender, where in a popup appears before the control is loaded. The issue is observed even in the sample provided in the site. http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/HTMLEditorExtender/HTMLEditorExtender.aspx

This can be seen when the page is refreshed or reloaded. It appears for a fraction of a second and vanishes. Although this popup does not cause any issues, it is quite uneasy and un-explainable behaviour.

Please advise if there is any solution for this issue.

Screen-shot of the Pop-Up
[image: Screen-shot]

Answer (score 0):

if I understood correctly then you're having problem when refreshing the page with the pop-up?

Add

```
if (!Postback)
{
  return;
}
```

In your Page_Load or if you have an override OnLoad in your codebehind?

Cheers!